# How I can translate Laravel Error Message in Danish Language

Tags: laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and my website is in Danish and English languages.

[image: Default Behavior]

Required Message

`De bannere:0 har ugyldige billeddimensioner.`

how i can translate this dynamic message from multiple images array

Comment: you can use this package: https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang

Comment: thanks for response but i don;t want to use any package.

Answer (score 0):

In `resources/lang/dk/validation.php` (where you should have already copied the `resources/lang/en/validation.php` you have the following field:

`'dimensions' => 'The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.',`

:attribute is your bannere.0, which can also be translated in `attributes` array that is in the same file, something like this:

```
'attributes' => [
    'banners.0' => 'howyousaybannersinDanish.0'
],
```